# adjust form controls according to the size of the window

Tags: vb.net, controls

I am trying to resize/ re-position controls based on the size of the form. This is the class i am using :
Public Class Resizer

```
    '----------------------------------------------------------
    ' ControlInfo
    ' Structure of original state of all processed controls
    '----------------------------------------------------------
    Private Structure ControlInfo
        Public name As String
        Public parentName As String
        Public leftOffsetPercent As Double
        Public topOffsetPercent As Double
        Public heightPercent As Double
        Public originalHeight As Integer
        Public originalWidth As Integer
        Public widthPercent As Double
        Public originalFontSize As Single
    End Structure

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' ctrlDict
    ' Dictionary of (control name, control info) for all processed controls
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private ctrlDict As Dictionary(Of String, ControlInfo) = New Dictionary(Of String, ControlInfo)

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' FindAllControls
    ' Recursive function to process all controls contained in the initially passed
    ' control container and store it in the Control dictionary
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Sub FindAllControls(thisCtrl As Control)

        '-- If the current control has a parent, store all original relative position
        '-- and size information in the dictionary.
        '-- Recursively call FindAllControls for each control contained in the
        '-- current Control
        For Each ctl As Control In thisCtrl.Controls
            Try
                If Not IsNothing(ctl.Parent) Then
                    Dim parentHeight = ctl.Parent.Height
                    Dim parentWidth = ctl.Parent.Width

                    Dim c As New ControlInfo
                    c.name = ctl.Name
                    c.parentName = ctl.Parent.Name
                    c.topOffsetPercent = Convert.ToDouble(ctl.Top) / Convert.ToDouble(parentHeight)
                    c.leftOffsetPercent = Convert.ToDouble(ctl.Left) / Convert.ToDouble(parentWidth)
                    c.heightPercent = Convert.ToDouble(ctl.Height) / Convert.ToDouble(parentHeight)
                    c.widthPercent = Convert.ToDouble(ctl.Width) / Convert.ToDouble(parentWidth)
                    c.originalFontSize = ctl.Font.Size
                    c.originalHeight = ctl.Height
                    c.originalWidth = ctl.Width
                    ctrlDict.Add(c.name, c)
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print(ex.Message)
            End Try

            If ctl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                FindAllControls(ctl)
            End If

        Next '-- For Each

    End Sub

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' ResizeAllControls
    ' Recursive function to resize and reposition all controls contained in the Control
    ' dictionary
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Sub ResizeAllControls(thisCtrl As Control, Optional wform As Form = Nothing)

        Dim fontRatioW As Single
        Dim fontRatioH As Single
        Dim fontRatio As Single
        Dim f As Font
        If IsNothing(wform) = False Then wform.Opacity = 0

        '-- Resize and reposition all controls in the passed control
        For Each ctl As Control In thisCtrl.Controls
            Try
                If Not IsNothing(ctl.Parent) Then
                    Dim parentHeight = ctl.Parent.Height
                    Dim parentWidth = ctl.Parent.Width

                    Dim c As New ControlInfo

                    Dim ret As Boolean = False
                    Try
                        '-- Get the current control's info from the control info dictionary
                        ret = ctrlDict.TryGetValue(ctl.Name, c)

                        '-- If found, adjust the current control based on control relative
                        '-- size and position information stored in the dictionary
                        If (ret) Then
                            '-- Size
                            ctl.Width = Int(parentWidth * c.widthPercent)
                            ctl.Height = Int(parentHeight * c.heightPercent)

                            '-- Position
                            ctl.Top = Int(parentHeight * c.topOffsetPercent)
                            ctl.Left = Int(parentWidth * c.leftOffsetPercent)

                            '-- Font
                            f = ctl.Font
                            fontRatioW = ctl.Width / c.originalWidth
                            fontRatioH = ctl.Height / c.originalHeight
                            fontRatio = (fontRatioW +
                            fontRatioH) / 2 '-- average change in control Height and Width
                            ctl.Font = New Font(f.FontFamily,
                            c.originalFontSize * fontRatio, f.Style)

                        End If
                    Catch
                    End Try
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

            '-- Recursive call for controls contained in the current control
            If ctl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                ResizeAllControls(ctl)
            End If
        Next '-- For Each
        If IsNothing(wform) = False Then wform.Opacity = 1

    End Sub

End Class
```

The problem with this code is that 
1) It flickers a lot while resizing the controls or moving them around. 
2) Some labels and buttons are moved around to random positions on the form and,
3) the size of the background image is not responsive to the size of the form (Not much knowledge on how to execute this.)

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a TableLayoutPanel would be easier than all that.

Comment: Could you elaborate? @Plutonix

Comment: He doe4sn't need to elaborate. He has given you the keyword: `TableLayoutPanel`. How it works is you now open Google or Bing or some other search engine and type that word in to find more information about it. As you learn more, you can refine your search terms to find more specific information. Stop sitting on your hands and expecting others to explain things that you can easily find for yourself with little effort. It seems that the more access top information we have, the less effort many are prepared to put in to find it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney true.

Comment: *dat be how dey doo*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually doing this, look into properties on the form such as "Dock", "Anchor".

Examples:

1. Setting dock to top (or bottom) will allow a module to always cover 
   the entire top (or bottom) of the form, keeping the height the same.
2. Setting dock to left (or right) will allow a module to always cover the entire left (or right) of the form, keeping the height the
   same.
3. Setting the anchor property to all of Top, Left, Right, Down will allow the control to expand as the form grows, but keep it's x/y top-left position.
4. Setting the anchor property to Top, Left, Right will allow the control to expand to the right as the form grows, but keep it's x/y top-left position
5. Setting the anchor property to Bottom, Right will allow the control to stay in a fixed position relative to the bottom corner of the form.